# grunt-sencha-dependencies to process the existing php project

Tags: extjs, gruntjs

I have a php+ext 4.1.1a project which have the index.php(not index.html) but without the app.js. It use MVC structure but I am fed up the sencha cmd. It keep giving me errors when parsing the js files.

But when I tried to use the grunt-sencha-dependencies:
https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-sencha-dependencies

I stucked when I tried to generate the js file lists:
1. I can't generate the app.json file from different versions of sencha cmd
2. I don't have the index.html and app.js grunt-sencha-dependencies required

My question is:
1. if I have a app.jsb3 file how can I generate the app.json file which can be used by grunt
2. Is there any way I have grunt to parse the js files though the index.php file instead of local html file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I gave up generating from app.json. Instead, I can generate from the index.html and app.js without problem.

Sencha Cmd is so messy!